# On component created hook call Action to fetch data from database and store it in state and then call Getter to get the data

Tags: vue.js, vuex

So basically I have this component and I am using its created hook to fetch data using vue-resource and VUEX action, storing that data in store and right after that trying to get that data using VUEX getter but I am unable to do so. Any work around or I am doing something wrong. I am new to Vue!

Component:

```
import { mapActions } from 'vuex';
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
  components: {
    categoryHeader: CategoryHeader,
    categoryFooter: CategoryFooter,
    AddCategory
  },
  data() {
      return {
        openCatAdd: false,
        categories: [],
        pagination: []
      }
  },
  methods: {
      ...mapActions([
          'getCategories'
      ]),
      ...mapGetters([
          'allCategories'
      ])
  },
  created() {
      this.getCategories(1);
      this.categories = this.allCategories();
    //   console.log(this.categories);
  }
};
```

Store:

```
import Vue from "vue";

const state = {
    categories: [],
};

const mutations = {
    setCategories: (state, payload) => {
        state.categories = payload;
    }
};

const actions = {
    getCategories: ({commit}, payload) => {
        Vue.http.get('categories?page='+payload)
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            commit('setCategories', data.data);
        }, error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }
}

const getters = {
    allCategories: state => {
        console.log(state.categories); 
       return state.categories;
    }
};

export default {
    state,
    mutations,
    actions,
    getters
};
```